# Can you explain this::javaClass in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

```
sealed class Genre{
sealed class Fiction : Genre(){
    object Classics: Fiction()
    object Fantasy: Fiction()
    object ScienceFiction: Fiction()
}
sealed class NonFiction: Genre(){
    object Biography: NonFiction()
    object Business: NonFiction()
    object Feminism: NonFiction()
    object Politics: NonFiction()
    object SelfHelp: NonFiction()
}

override fun toString(): String {
    return this::javaClass.get().simpleName
}
```

I do not understand this context return this::javaClass...

When I press ctrl and hover over "this" it points to Genre class, This is confusing me.

Comment: `this` refers to the current receiver (the instance of class of the innermost scope it appears in). At runtime, it will be whatever Genre or Genre subtype class instance is having `toString()` called on it.  `::javaclass` gets the `Class` of the class instance you call it on.

Comment: Can you please give some examples?

Comment: I'm not clear on which part you don't understand.

Comment: what I do not understand
'
 this::javaClass
'
is that means we are  just accessing the method getSimpleName()

Comment: I think this code is in fact a little confusing. because someone made a mistake in it. `this::javaClass` does not return `Class<Fantasy>`, but `KProperty`. It should be: `this.javaClass.simpleName`.

Comment: Yes, But your first comment put me in the way.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, `::javaClass.get()` is a roundabout way to get `.javaClass`. It would sort of be like calling `::toString.invoke()` instead of just `.toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe someone made a mistake in this code, making it a little confusing. What he/she really meant was:

```
this.javaClass.simpleName
```

Let's analyze it step by step:

1. `this.javaClass` creates `Class` object for provided `this` object. It could return e.g. `Class<Fantasy>`.
2. `this::javaClass` creates a property accessor for `javaClass` property of `this` object. It can be used later to access `javaClass` of `this`.
3. `get()` is called on property accessor to get the `javaClass` of `this`.
4. This way `get()` returned e.g. `Class<Fantasy>` and `simpleName` returned the name of a class.

I'm not sure if this explanation is at all possible to understand. But what is important is that `this::javaClass.get()` is the same as simply `this.javaClass`, probably done by a mistake.